# Can I tail the log of ONE container in a docker-compose group?

Tags: docker-compose, prometheus

I'm still struggling to understand why my ipmi_exporter container will not run in the same "pod" as my Prometheus, Grafana, snmp_exporter and alertmanager. When I bring up the "pod," *docker-compose* *says* ipmi_exporter has started but *docker-compose ps* cannot find the container. I'd like to be able to see the log containing the startup for ipmi_exporter, if that was not made clear in my post title.

Also, what is a docker-compose group of containers called? Pods are a K8s thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `docker-compose` binary only commands the docker daemon. You can simply use the `docker` command to get what you need.

Use `docker ps` or `docker ps -a` to find out about your containers.

Use `docker logs ...` with container name to get logs out of a particular container. This works even if you have redirected your logs elsewhere in compose file.

Docker itself sort-of does not have a notion of a "pod". The closest you can get is to define a `stack` which is a collection of networks, volumes and containers - this is similar to K8s pod. Also, the `stack` is actually what you define in docker-compose.yml file.